# Override Daylight Savings Time configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, timezone, daylight-saving

All the computers on my network (2003 Server AD) are configured to get their Time updates from the PDC-Emulator.  The PDC gets updates from time.windows.com.  The system is in Israel where we have no standard rules for the change between DST/Standard Time (actually, they sometimes change the rules only weeks before the expected clock change), so the built in DST rules are not accurate.

Is there any way to override the built in DST settings for my time zone (Jerusalem +2 UTC) so that my users see the right time regardless of what MS thinks the time is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DST rules *should* be updated by Microsoft but experience suggests this cannot be relied upon, at least not in a timely fashion. There is a utility called tzedit.exe which you can use to edit the rules manually, although I cannot recall if it's part of the system, an add-on pack or something else. Just be aware that the standard rule files may get overwritten by Windows updates, so it's best to create a new custom configuration instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unselect the option to "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time".

Comment: That will only help to get the systems off of DST when the system thinks they should be on it.  What about when I want to get them on to DST when the system says they should not be?

Comment: Then change the time on the PDC emulator to what you want it to be. All other DC's will sync to the PDC emulator and all clients will sync to their authenticating DC.